# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ and $S^{n-1}\times \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$. I read some related questions and am thinking of the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}^+$ given by $$f(x)=(\dfrac{x}{||x||},||x||).$$ I understand that it is continuous but what is its inverse? I don't seem to see it... If I prove this is a homeomorphism, then since $\mathbb{R}^+\cong\mathbb{R}$ (by the exponential, right?) I get $$\mathbb{R}^+\cong\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}^+\cong\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$$ and by transitivity I get my result.
Any help finding the inverse would be great!

Comment: isn't $\mathbb{R^n}\cong\mathbb{S^n}$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No. Precisely one of those is compact.

Comment: i thought that was Poincare's conjecture - which has been proven

Comment: I'm sorry, but that has nothing to do with the Poincare conjecture.

Comment: okay, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse is of course $(s,r)\mapsto rs$. Note that $\frac x{\|x\|}\cdot \|x\|=x$.

Comment: Yes, it is totally obvious, my bad! Thank you very much!